# view photo taken in landscape orientation, in "portrait" orientation for review, and save so it's not rotated

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-vision-camera, react-native-orientation-locker

I am using `"react-native-vision-camera": "^2.15.4",` in my Expo project (SDK 46, RN, 0.69.9).  The `expo-camera` module doesn't support different lenses, hence the switch.

When i take a picture in either portrait or landscape orientation, the photo is showing as `photo.metadata.Orientation: 6`

This surprises me.

[image]
[image]

I want the preview of the image, after the photo has been taken, to be rotated so that it's horizontal and easier to view.  It also saves vertically so on the web, it's also rotated incorrectly.

```
<Camera
  // Do not add enableZoomGesture since using the Animated lib
  // enableZoomGesture
  ref={cameraRef}
  photo
  device={device}
  isActive={isActive}
  format={formats?.[0]}
  animatedProps={animatedProps}
  orientation={'portrait'}
/>
```

Apparently, the [`orientation` prop](https://www.react-native-vision-camera.com/docs/api/interfaces/CameraProps#orientation) in the Camera component is also not functioning as expected.

Why is the orientation the same on the metadata?
How can I get the photo to rotate correctly after it's been taken, so it's saved for viewing in a horizontal "portrait" orientation?

---

EDIT
I have since tried the `react-native-orientation-locker`.  And while it doesn't lock the image being captured, I can at least customize the image now after the capture event:

```
const capturePhoto = async () => {
    if (cameraRef?.current && !snapping) {
      setSnapping(true);
      const photo = await cameraRef.current.takePhoto({
        flash: flashMode,
      });

      let rotation = 0;

      if (orientation === OrientationType['LANDSCAPE-LEFT']) {
        rotation = -90;
      } else if (orientation === OrientationType['LANDSCAPE-RIGHT']) {
        rotation = 90;
      } else if (orientation === OrientationType['PORTRAIT-UPSIDEDOWN']) {
        rotation = 180;
      }

     // now use `expo-image-manipulator`
      const photoWithOrientation = await manipulateImage({
        imageUri: photo.path,
        actions: [{ rotate: rotation }],
        saveOptions: {
          compress: 1,
        },
      });

      handleSaveAsset([
        {
          path: photoWithOrientation.uri,
          width: photoWithOrientation.width,
          height: photoWithOrientation.height,
          isRawPhoto: false,
        },
      ]);
    }
  };
```

Is there a way to remove this logic so the image is always "vertical" on review, or is this the correct approach?

Comment: Any feedback for?

Comment: at this point, I think it's a know issue in the library & appears to have a bounty for it:
https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera/issues/1891

Answer (score -1):

```
         <Camera
          ref={camera}
          style={[StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject]}
          device={device}
          isActive={true}
          zoom={0}
          photo
          orientation={'portrait'}
        />
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**