# react-native-vision-camera set photo orientation to landscape

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-camera, react-native-vision-camera

I'm trying to capture photo and make it landscape. Im using `orientation='landscape-left'` inside my `Camera` component.
However, when I take picture, it still saving the photo as `portrait`.
I blocked application rotation so the app always stays `portrait`. However, I need to take the picture `landscape`.

```
<Camera
          ref={camera}
          style={[StyleSheet.absoluteFill]}
          device={device}
          photo
          orientation='landscape-left'
          isActive={true}/>

        <View style={styles.cameraButtons}>
          <Pressable onPress={() => takePhoto()}>
            <Icons name="camera" size={54} style={styles.cameraIcon}/>
          </Pressable>
</View>
```

Answer (score -1):

[This post sorta worked for me.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76103589/view-photo-taken-in-landscape-orientation-in-portrait-orientation-for-review)
Using sensor libraries with Android in general seem to be very picky about what versions will work together. Might be able to use document context to rotate the image. Something like this:

```js
function rotateImage(imageSrc: string, degrees: number): HTMLCanvasElement {
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = imageSrc;

    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    if (!ctx) {
        throw new Error('Unable to get canvas context');
    }

    img.onload = () => {
        // Set canvas size to the same as the image
        canvas.width = img.width;
        canvas.height = img.height;

        // Translate context to center of canvas
        ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);

        ctx.rotate((degrees * Math.PI) / 180);

        // Draw the image, adjusted so its center is at the canvas's 0,0 coordinates
        ctx.drawImage(img, -img.width / 2, -img.height / 2);

        // Reset the transformation matrix to the identity matrix
        ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    };

    return canvas;
}
```

I also created a [bug report](https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera/issues/2330#issue-2060969478) with RNVC for this same issue yesterday for a similar issue regarding the orientation prop in the camera component itself. Hopefully this issue will be resolved soon.